# Добавление архива tar.gz в свой репозиторий на git

Tags: python, bitbucket, git, javascript, github

Есть ли такая возможность: загрузка целого архива себе в репозиторий, а не по отдельному файлику редактируя? Если есть, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что означает "по отдельному файлику, рекдактируя".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эм, вы имеете в виду git [push](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8#Push)?

Я так понимаю, вы все пытаетесь делать через web-gui? Это не есть хорошо. Вернее, вам, скорее всего, надо просто почитать pro-git. Да и вообще, что вы подразумеваете под добавлением архива? Имеете в виду, что вам надозапушить директорию?

Answer (score 1):

Именно содержимое? Или нужна фиксация самого факт наличия этого файла в репозитории? Возможно, подойдёт [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).